# Write on a closed net.Conn but returned nil error

Tags: sockets, go, tcp, connection

Talk is cheap, so here we go the simple code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    addr := "127.0.0.1:8999"

    // Server
    go func() {
        tcpaddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", addr)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        listen, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpaddr)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        for  {
            if conn, err := listen.Accept(); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            } else if conn != nil {
                go func(conn net.Conn) {
                    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
                    n, err := conn.Read(buffer)
                    if err != nil {
                        fmt.Println(err)
                    } else {
                        fmt.Println(">", string(buffer[0 : n]))
                    }
                    conn.Close()
                }(conn)
            }
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    // Client
    if conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", addr); err == nil {
        for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
            _, err := conn.Write([]byte("hello"))
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                conn.Close()
                break
            } else {
                fmt.Println("ok")
            }
            // sleep 10 seconds and re-send
            time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
        }
    } else {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

**Ouput:**

```
> hello
ok
ok
```

The Client writes to the Server twice. After the first read, the Server closes the connection immediately, but the Client **sleeps 10 seconds** and then re-writes to the Server with the same **already closed** connection object(`conn`).

Why can the second write succeed (returned error is nil)?

Can anyone help?

PS:

In order to check if the buffering feature of the system affects the result of the second write, I edited the Client like this, but it still succeeds:

```
// Client
if conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", addr); err == nil {
    _, err := conn.Write([]byte("hello"))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        conn.Close()
        return
    } else {
        fmt.Println("ok")
    }
    // sleep 10 seconds and re-send
    time.Sleep(10*time.Second)

    b := make([]byte, 400000)
    for i := range b {
        b[i] = 'x'
    }
    n, err := conn.Write(b)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        conn.Close()
        return
    } else {
        fmt.Println("ok", n)
    }
    // sleep 10 seconds and re-send
    time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
} else {
    panic(err)
}
```

And here is the screenshot:
[attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBYF4.png)

Comment: The 'connection object' is *not* 'already closed'. The *connection* is already closed by the peer, but this doesn't get noticed by the local TCP until the local application executes another I/O. The connection *object* is not 'already closed' at this point.

Comment: @EJP Yes, so it does a second write( this can be another I/O ), even using big bytes, it still gives a nil error - which means it does not detect the close action. But why?

Answer (score 9):

There are several problems with your approach.

#### Sort-of a preface

The first one is that you do not wait for the server goroutine
to complete.
In Go, once `main()` exits for whatever reason,
all the other goroutines still running, if any, are simply
teared down forcibly.

You're trying to "synchronize" things using timers,
but this only works in toy situations, and even then it
does so only from time to time.

Hence let's fix your code first:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    addr := "127.0.0.1:8999"

    tcpaddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    listener, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpaddr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Server
    done := make(chan error)
    go func(listener net.Listener, done chan<- error) {
        for {
            conn, err := listener.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                done <- err
                return
            }
            go func(conn net.Conn) {
                var buffer [1024]byte
                n, err := conn.Read(buffer[:])
                if err != nil {
                    log.Println(err)
                } else {
                    log.Println(">", string(buffer[0:n]))
                }
                if err := conn.Close(); err != nil {
                    log.Println("error closing server conn:", err)
                }
            }(conn)
        }
    }(listener, done)

    // Client
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        _, err := conn.Write([]byte("hello"))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            err = conn.Close()
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("error closing client conn:", err)
            }
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("ok")
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }

    // Shut the server down and wait for it to report back
    err = listener.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error closing listener:", err)
    }
    err = <-done
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("server returned:", err)
    }
}
```

> I've spilled a couple of minor fixes
>   like using `log.Fatal` (which is
>   `log.Print` + `os.Exit(1)`) instead of panicking,
>   removed useless `else` clauses to adhere to the coding standard of keeping the main
>   flow where it belongs, and lowered the client's timeout. 
>   I have also added checking for possible errors `Close` on sockets may return.

The interesting part is that we now properly shut the server down by closing the listener and then waiting for the server goroutine to report back (unfortunately Go does not return an error of a custom type from `net.Listener.Accept` in this case so we can't really check that `Accept` exited because we've closed the listener).
Anyway, our goroutines are now properly synchronized, and there is
no undefined behaviour, so we can reason about how the code works.

#### Remaining problems

Some problems still remain.

The more glaring is you making wrong assumption that TCP preserves
message boundaries—that is, if you write "hello" to the client
end of the socket, the server reads back "hello".
This is not true: TCP considers both ends of the connection
as producing and consuming *opaque streams of bytes.*
This means, when the client writes "hello", the client's
TCP stack is free to deliver "he" and postpone sending "llo",
and the server's stack is free to yield "hell" to the `read`
call on the socket and only return "o" (and possibly some other
data) in a later `read`.

So, to make the code "real" you'd need to somehow introduce these
message boundaries into the protocol above TCP.
In this particular case the simplest approach would be either
using "messages" consisting of a fixed-length and agreed-upon
endianness prefix indicating the length of the following
data and then the string data itself.
The server would then use a sequence like

```
var msg [4100]byte
_, err := io.ReadFull(sock, msg[:4])
if err != nil { ... }
mlen := int(binary.BigEndian.Uint32(msg[:4]))
if mlen < 0 {
  // handle error
}
if mlen == 0 {
  // empty message; goto 1
}
_, err = io.ReadFull(sock, msg[5:5+mlen])
if err != nil { ... }
s := string(msg[5:5+mlen])
```

Another approach is to agree on that the messages do not contain
newlines and terminate each message with a newline
(ASCII LF, `\n`, 0x0a).
The server side would then use something like
a usual [`bufio.Scanner` loop](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#example_Scanner_lines) to get
full lines from the socket.

The remaining problem with your approach is to not dealing with
what `Read` on a socket returns: note that `io.Reader.Read`
(that's what sockets implement, among other things) is allowed
to return an error *while having had read some data* from the
underlying stream. In your toy example this might rightfully
be unimportant, but suppose that you're writing a `wget`-like
tool which is able to *resume* downloading of a file: even if
reading from the server returned *some* data and an error, you
have to deal with that returned chunk first and only then
handle the error.

#### Back to the problem at hand

The problem presented in the question, I beleive, happens simply because in your setup you hit some TCP buffering problem due to the tiny length of your messages.

On my box which runs Linux 4.9/amd64 two things reliably "fix"
the problem:

- Sending messages of 4000 bytes in length: the second call
  to `Write` "sees" the problem immediately.
- Doing more `Write` calls.

For the former, try something like

```
msg := make([]byte, 4000)
for i := range msg {
    msg[i] = 'x'
}
for {
    _, err := conn.Write(msg)
    ...
```

and for the latter—something like

```
for {
    _, err := conn.Write([]byte("hello"))
    ...
    fmt.Println("ok")
    time.Sleep(time.Second / 2)
}
```

(it's sensible to lower the pause between sending stuff in
both cases).

It's interesting to note that the former example hits the
`write: connection reset by peer` (`ECONNRESET` in POSIX)
error while the second one hits `write: broken pipe`
(`EPIPE` in POSIX).

This is because when we're sending in chunks worth 4k bytes,
some of the packets generated for the stream manage to become
"in flight" before the server's side of the connection manages
to propagate the information on its closure to the client,
and those packets hit an already closed socket and get rejected
with the `RST` TCP flag set.
In the second example an attempt to send another chunk of data
sees that the client side already knows that the connection
has been teared down and fails the sending without "touching
the wire".

#### TL;DR, the bottom line

Welcome to the wonderful world of networking. ;-)

I'd recommend buying a copy of "TCP/IP Illustrated",
read it and experiment.
TCP (and IP and other protocols above IP)
sometimes works not like people expect them to by applying
their "common sense".

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I'd like to illustrate the question as simple as possible, so I shorted these codes in order not to attention to the details.  

About the main problem. Yes, doing more writes can make the socket know the closed connection. But should it give an error when writing on a closed connection? Which makes me quite confused.

Comment: I test the codes again, writing quite a big bytes in the second request:

    msg := make([]byte, 40000)
    for i := range msg {
        msg[i] = 'x'
    }

but the result is as the same before: it returns a nil error. So I do not think buffer can cause such result. This also confused me alot.

Comment: I post the codes and relational screenshot to the bottom of the question.

Comment: @Claymore: as explained in detail, the connection is not closed at that point. A normal closing of a connection doesn't happen until both sids send FIN-ACK. If you want to send more data then you may eventually get an RST and a broken pipe, but you can't somehow expect a synchronous error from your erroneous packets.

Comment: @JimB Yes, in order for the connection to close normally (both sides send and get FIN-ACK), the second write **sleep 10 second** to send its request, but the second write cannot detect the closure, why? I even make a big bytes for the second write to send immediately, but still got "ok", why?

Comment: @Claymore, you detect a TCP close by reading from a connection, not by writing. If this still doesn’t make sense, I suggest taking some time to learn how the underlying TCP protocol works.